# Ajax.Actionlink, partial and webgrid issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I have the following issue.

My url structure is like this:

/people/edit/usercode

In my controller i have the following:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public PartialViewResult LoanRefresh(string id)
    {
        PeopleModel p = new PeopleModel();
        return PartialView("_LoanHistory", p.getPersonLoanHistory(id));

    }
```

In my view i have:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Refresh", "LoanRefresh", new { id = Model.IdentityCode }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "loanHistory", LoadingElementId = "Loading"  }, new { @class = "button" })
```

and

```
 <div id="loanHistory">
    @Html.Partial("_LoanHistory", Model.Loans)
 </div>
```

When run the Ajax.ActionLink it gets the data back ok and it updates the div, but the url of the sort links on the webgrid then change their address to:

/People/**LoanRefresh**/AFU0006?sort=CreatedOn&sortdir=ASC

i need to stay as:

/People/**Edit**/AFU0006?sort=CreatedOn&sortdir=ASC

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? please post your update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well @Nick, that's because your action name is **LoanRefresh** and not **Refresh**. To do that you will probably have to do some **routing** or even redirect your LoanRefresh results to an action named Refresh.

Comment: Thankyou Adriano, i will look further into Routing.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `ajaxUpdateContainerId` to an object that is specified in the partial view, rather than an object in the view from which the partial view is originally called. The sort URLs should work correctly then.