# Ajax.Actionlink, partial and webgrid issue

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, refresh, webgrid

The issue is same as the one posted here [Ajax.Actionlink, partial and webgrid issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931869/ajax-actionlink-partial-and-webgrid-issue)

The solution to use "Refresh" method does not work for me because I have three webgrids in my page. Please suggest how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You webgrid is obviously using AJAX, i just didnt use AJAX to solve my issue.

Obviously not a real solution, but i will do for now until i can sit down and look at it again.

Btw i am the OP from that thread.